# How to deserialize an XML with a nested array elements?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

Deserialization of XML file with nested array of elements

I've searched but can't see any helpful examples.

this is my XML sample:

```
<trans>
  <orderNo>0001</orderNo>
  <orderDate>08/07/2014</orderDate>
  <orders>
    <item>
      <itemName>item1</itemName>
      <itemAmount>200</itemAmount>
      <itemMeasures>
        <measure>each</measure>
        <measure>case</measure>
      </itemMeasures>
    </item>
    <item>
      <itemName>item2</itemName>
      <itemAmount>100</itemAmount>
      <itemMeasures>
        <measure>each</measure>
        <measure>case</measure>
      </itemMeasures>
    </item>
  </orders>
</trans>
```

Comment: how do your model classes look like?

Comment: `I've searched but can't see any helpful examples` Hard to believe. One of the mostly covered topics

Answer (score 3):

You must create classes for each of the structures you have in the XML and then using XmlSerializer and the method Deserialize of the object from that class you can create nested arrays with the values. If you want code and example, please edit your post with the full xml structure.
See the example below for part of your xml:

```
[XmlType("trans")]
public class Trans
{
    [XmlElement("orderNo")]
    public string OrderNo { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("orderDate")]
    public string OrderDate { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("orders")]
    public HashSet<Item> Orders { get; set; }
}

[XmlType("item")]
public class Item
{
    [XmlElement("itemName")]
    public string ItemName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("itemAmount")]
    public string ItemAmount { get; set; }
}
```

The the Deserialization code is:

```
XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Trans[]), new XmlRootAttribute("trans"));
using (FileStream myFileStream = new FileStream("XmlFile.xml", FileMode.Open))
{
    Trans[] r;
    r = (Trans[])mySerializer.Deserialize(myFileStream);
}
```